# JSON columns sorting with Footable

Tags: jquery, footable

I am using footable to display a huge table. I am displaying the columns in json:

```
"columns": $.get("/masteradmin/full-report-columns/", postdata_columns, 'json'),
```

I want to sort the month columns by default. How I can set a `data-sort-initial="descending"` variable in the json?

```
{
    "name": "month",
    "title": str(_("Month")),
    "type": "date",
    "formatString": "MMMM YYYY"
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The examples show how to achieve this: http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/components/sorting.html#options

```
{
    "name": "month",
    "title": str(_("Month")),
    "type": "date",
    "formatString": "MMMM YYYY",
    "sorted": true,
    "direction": "DESC"
},
```